# I am stuck in a infinite while loop and can't understand why

Tags: c#

So I am working in console and asking a user to enter their option by pressing 1 or 2 but I need to stop them from pressing anything else and thus I am trying to use this code but it just loops endlessly

```
while(userInputInt2 != 2 || userInputInt2 != 1)
{
Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------");
Console.WriteLine("--INVALID OPTION SELECTED                      --");
Console.WriteLine("--Please Select an Option Below                --");
Console.WriteLine("--Return To Main Menu (1)                      --");
Console.WriteLine("--Exit                (2)                      --");
Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------");
Console.Write("--Selected Option: ");
userInput = Console.ReadLine();
userInputInt2 = Int32.Parse(userInput);
}
```

Comment: it's because your condition always true by design.

Comment: Use `&&` instead of `||` - if `userInputInt2 == 2` then also `userInputInt2 != 1`, and vice versa.

Comment: Maybe you need to read this: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because you've used `or`.

It's always either not 1 OR not 2

I think you want:

```
while(userInputInt2 != 2 && userInputInt2 != 1)
```

Comment: Thank you. Cant believe i missed something so simple.

Answer (score 1):

Just edit your code as below

```
while(userInputInt2 != 2 && userInputInt2 != 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("--INVALID OPTION SELECTED                      --");
    Console.WriteLine("--Please Select an Option Below                --");
    Console.WriteLine("--Return To Main Menu (1)                      --");
    Console.WriteLine("--Exit                (2)                      --");
    Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------");
    Console.Write("--Selected Option: ");
    userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    userInputInt2 = Int32.Parse(userInput);
}
```

this will loop as long as your *userInputInt2* value is not 1 AND not 2 but will stop and exit the loop if the *userInputInt2* equals 1 or equals 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following that is better

```
    while (new List<int> {1, 2}.All(x => x != userInputInt2))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("--INVALID OPTION SELECTED                      --");
        Console.WriteLine("--Please Select an Option Below                --");
        Console.WriteLine("--Return To Main Menu (1)                      --");
        Console.WriteLine("--Exit                (2)                      --");
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------");
        Console.Write("--Selected Option: ");
        userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        userInputInt2 = Int32.Parse(userInput);
    }
```